# Boostrap - Menú de navegación dejar marcado el item seleccionado

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

Tengo un menú de navegación con boostrap, uso el motor de plantillas blade y tengo jquery +boostrap 4 en el layout.

El header que tengo es este

```
    <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="home" href="{{ route('front.user.pages.home') }}">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a id="perfil-usuario" href="{{ route('front.user.profile.show') }}">Perfil usuario</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->

    <a href="#about" class="get-started-btn scrollto">Empieza ya!</a>

</div>
```

Y lo que intento hacer es que cuando **el usuario haga click** en cada uno de los botones como puede ser "**Inicio**" o "**Perfil usuario**" que no deja de ser un link a una ruta, cuando cargue la página deje el botón marcado como tal.

La única forma que lo he conseguido que seguramente sea la "peor" en cuanto a mantenimiento es mirando la "URI" que recibo y si la uri coincide con algunos de los botones, mediante jquery le añado la clase "active"

Algo asi.

```
    @php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/perfil-usuario') {
         $("#perfil-usuario").addClass("active");
    }
    @endphp
```

Comment: No creo que sea la "peor" forma... pero puedes comprobar la ruta (route) con el helper `url()->current()`, ej. `route('front.user.pages.home') === url()->current() ? 'active' : ''`... lo puedes meter en una función etc....

Comment: Pero entonces el código que tengo seria tal como este y abajo incluiría un trozo de código que comprueba la url? gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No haría la comprobación en el ejemplo que haz puesto, no es muy óptimo.

Te dejo una posible solución, donde te creas una función global y luego en tu código (blade), pasas la ruta:

BLADE:

```
<li class="{{ checkCurrentRouteByName(route('front.user.pages.home')) ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a id="home" href="{{ route('front.user.pages.home') }}">
        Inicio
    </a>
</li>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

function checkCurrentRouteByName(string $route): bool
{
    return $route === url()->current();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, así lo he implementado.